# Generate random number with jinja2

Tags: python-2.7, flask, jinja2

I need to generate a random number between 1 and 50. Aparently the random filter needs a [sequence](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#random). How can I create a list with numbers from 1 to 50 in Jinja?

```
{{ [1,n,50]|random() }}
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Jinja2 also includes the [`range`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-globals.range) function which returns a sequence of numbers from `start` to `end - 1`, so you can use it with [`random`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.random):

```
Your lucky number is: {{ range(1, 51) | random }}
```

Answer (score 0):

This alternative allows you to generate a random number in a custom way; and use the generated number in multiple places inside the template.

```
from jinja2 import Template
import random

jT = Template(
    '''
    {% set ppid = randint(1, 51)  %}
    {"initial": {{ppid}}, "expected": {{ppid}}, "default": "{{default}}"}
    ''')

jT.globals.update({
    "randint": random.randint  # Method used to generate the number
})

params = {'default': "11111111"}
print(jT.render(**params))
```