# passing random numbers into template from flask python

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, jinja2, mod-wsgi

If I use the `random` module and use something like `num = random.randint(1,1000)` and pass `num` as a variable into `render_template()`, it works but the number does not change the number when I refresh the page. It only changes if I run the app again or restart Apache.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted a minimal example of your python and html code.

Comment: Yes, please post a minimal example of your code. I have just tried this and was able to get it working first time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate random number with jinja2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36683951/generate-random-number-with-jinja2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**app.py**

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    random_number = random.randint(1, 1000)
    return render_template('index.html', random_number=random_number)
```

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <p> {{ random_number }} is your random number. </p>
<\body>
```

I have tested that this generates a new random number on refresh.

Comment: Super .. Thanks .. I was doing the exact same thing except that I was generating the random number outside the route . Will make sure next time to post a small snippet of the code ;)

Can you possibly explain why this does not work if I generate the random rumber outside the route ?

Comment: Because otherwise the random number is in the context of the application (assigned once when the app loads). You rather want it to be (re-)assigned in the context of each request, i.e. in the scope of the function that handles requests on the index page.

Comment: Makes sense .. Thanks a lot