# Can't use Jinja elements on Page

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2

I am working on Django and new to Jinja templates. I am able to print variable from the context  but can't use  other features of Jinja.

When I do {{ 1+1 }} on the page . it shows:

> Could not parse the remainder: '+1' from '1+1'

I am trying to generate a random no.  by {{ range(1, 51) | random }} ,As  by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36683951/generate-random-number-with-jinja2)  answer. but it throws error as:

> Could not parse some characters: range|(1, 51)| | random

**In settings.py :**

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you didn't activate Jinja2 template in your Django project. Please set the Template Engine properly.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
         'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
         ...
```

Comment: New to Django configurations. Deleted that backed line.Now I am getting "__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context_processors'".

Comment: If you included your hole Django settings in your question then it will be helpful us to debug more...! Also what is your Django version...

Comment: I am using Django version 1.10, will update code in question.

Answer (score 0):

```
TEMPLATES = [{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates', # remove this line
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
}]
```

In line 3 you override key `BACKEND` with Django Template Engine.

Comment: Deleted that backed line.Now I am getting "__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context_processors'".

Comment: What is the version of the Django?

Comment: Django version is 1.10

Comment: If you don't need `context_processors` you can use `OPTIONS: {}`, but if you need them, then you need to upgrade to version 1.11.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2