# Why does Jinja2 range() function cannot be parsed? "TemplateSyntaxError, Could not parse some characters...". Generating random number in Jinja2

Tags: python, html, django, jinja2, django-template-filters

I want to add random number to the URL of the static file I am loading (because otherwise static file is cashed and not refreshing). But when I try to load the page The following is displayed:

> Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
>
> Exception Value: Could not parse some characters: range|(1, 51)| | random

My snippets:

in wrapper.html (inside head tag)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}?v={{ range(1, 51) | random }}" 
      type="text/css"/>
```

in settings.py (Maybe something wrong here)

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I have looked at this question [Generate random number with jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36683951/generate-random-number-with-jinja2) and used the same line suggested in the answer, but it didn't work.

Thank you very much

Comment: `range()` is not a Django template tag, you should generate the random number in your view and pass it to the template.

Comment: You are not using Jinja2, you are using Django template language. That language does not permit calling functions with parameters.